# Why do my Command Prompts have inconsistent fonts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, fonts

In the directory `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, I open the `cmd.exe` and set the font as `DejaVu Sans Mono`. It works.

However, in the directory `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools`, I open the shortcut `Command Prompt`, the font is `新宋体` rather than `DejaVu Sans Mono` I just set.

Then, I right click the shortcut `Command Prompt`, and set the font as `DejaVu Sans Mono` in the properties.

After setting the font, I reopen the shortcut `Command Prompt`, the font remains `新宋体`, how to solve this inconsistency?

[image: see image of the font setting process described above]

Comment: Set the font through the "Defaults" menu not the "Properties" menu. Properties is the current window (shortcut) only. Defaults is all windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill I just try setting through "Defaults" menu, but the font of the current window doesn't change. When I reopened the cmd, the font still remains 新宋体.

Comment: Hmm. Works fine on Windows 7.